# Facebook sharing images from an iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having an issue with sharing an image on Facebook, from an iOS app.
([See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594505/trying-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-from-an-ios-app))
I read that it was against Facebook policy to prefill text before sharing.
Is it also contrary to their policy to prefill an image?

I can understand that prefilling can lead to possible exagerations. But in an app dealing with pictures, if I cannot make it easy for the user to share his picture by preloading it; what could be the point of having a FB button in my app?

Answer (score 2):

As my understanding, we can't prefill text, however, can share photos from your application to Facebook and there is no restriction of that. As they said, there are just some requirements

- Photos must be less than 12MB in size
- People need the native Facebook for iOS app installed, version 7.0 or higher.

Here is the example code of using FBSDKSharePhotoContent to share photos via FB

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
  photo.image = image;
  photo.userGenerated = YES;
  FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
  content.photos = @[photo];
  ...
}
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: Thanks! I am happy to see that we share the same understanding. I hope we are right.
And the code in my other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594505/trying-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-from-an-ios-app) is very much based on the document you mentioned as reference, which I also read before. But my share is not working(i.e. the photo shows up on my FB, but not on other people's FB and I get this message I mentioned.)

Answer (score 1):

I also try to find out how to share a image to Facebook and their documentation didn't help me a lot -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/content-types/

In the end I manage to do it in this way:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit

private func shareInFacebook() {
        let photo = SharePhoto(image: image!, userGenerated: true)
        let content = SharePhotoContent()
        content.photos = [photo]
        let showDialog = ShareDialog(fromViewController: self, content: content, delegate: self)

        if (showDialog.canShow) {
            showDialog.show()
        } else {
            self.view.makeToast("It looks like you don't have the Facebook mobile app on your phone.")
        }
}
```

Hope this will help someone ;)